# How to find third point with given angle and distance

Tags: javascript, drawing

I am developing a drawing app with FabricJS. I have developed so far, that it draw lines from Point a to Point b, From point b to point c. And display length and angle between two lines.

Now I like to add feature to change angle of Point B and redraw second line.

I was looking for calculation that if I have point of a and b, angle and distance then find out new point of c as per give angle and distance. Please see attached image.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let the vector `a->b` be `(x, y)`. Then the perpendicular vector to it, rotated clockwise, is `(y, -x)`.

[image]

Compute their normalized vectors:

[image]

Then using coordinate systems

[image] (EDIT: + b)